# Count query help required

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have users with fix 28 CheckList Items where on daily basis user has to enter value infront of every checklist item.

Users sometimes partially filled the list or leave it incomplete so i need to show them that you have left the checklist INCOMPLETE or filled PARTIALLY so therefore maintaining a field called "trans_status" which by default goes in database with 0 means Incomplete and once user fills the data the value gets 1 and it 28 entries has mixed 1 and 0's it means PARTIAL and if all 28 enties has 0 means INCOMPLETE and if all 1 means COMPLETED.

Here is the structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VTRCheckListDetails](
    [userid] [int] NULL,
    [branchid] [int] NULL,
    [vtrRespDate] [date] NULL,
    [CLid] [int] NULL,
    [VtrValue] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [trans_status] [int] NULL,
    [last_updated] [int] NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And here is the sample data

```
INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','1','1','1','0')

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','2','2','0','0')    

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','3','3','0','0')      

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','4','4','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','5','5','0','0')     

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','6','6','0','0')  

 INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','7','7','0','0')  

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','8','8','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','9','9','0','0')  

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','10','10','0','0')  

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','11','11','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','12','12','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','13','13','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','14','14','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','15','15','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','16','16','0','0')  

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','17','17','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','18','18','0','0')  

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','19','19','0','0')  

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','20','20','0','0')  

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','21','21','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','22','22','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','23','23','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','24','24','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','25','25','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','26','26','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','27','27','0','0')   

INSERT VTRCheckListDetails(userid,branchid,vtrRespDate,CLid,VtrValue,trans_status,last_updated)       VALUES('144','14','2010-12-30','28','28','0','0')
```

What i want is when i run the query it should group on dates and show the data like this based on trans_status

```
Date.............Status
30-12-12..........Partial (can be complete, incomplete)
```

Comment: Please use better grammar and punctuation in your second paragraph.  I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking for.

Comment: ... Although maybe I spoke too soon. You are inserting `0` into a date column (`last_updated`). Doesn't work for me.

Comment: appology for my poor english. well dont get mislead i have given you the table structure and status field is trans_status with every checklist entry. need to group on date and need count on all 28 entries and check if all 28 has 1 or all 28 has 0 or all 28 has mixed 1 and 0's and based on that need to show the status. Hope i am making sense now :)

Comment: The scripts are working now. +1 for posting them, BTW. All do like @user342944 does!

Comment: Not deducting, but the DML (INSERTs) aren't that useful. You're inserting char values into int and date columns because of the quoted values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  vtrRespDate,
        CASE COUNT(CASE trans_status WHEN 1 THEN 1 END)
        WHEN 0 THEN
                'Incomplete'
        WHEN COUNT(*) THEN
                'Complete'
        ELSE
                'Partial'
        END AS Status
FROM    VTRCheckListDetails
GROUP BY
        vtrRespDate
```

Comment: Quassnoi bravooooooooooooo...nice and simple..excellent and many thanks for the great query

Comment: Nice ? case .. when .. without else ? But I admit interesting. Make it CASE SUM(CASE trans_status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: @bernd_k: `ELSE NULL` is implied when `ELSE` is omitted.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT   userid     ,
         vtrRespDate,
         CASE
                  WHEN MAX(trans_status) = 0
                  THEN 'InComplete'
                  WHEN MIN(trans_status)=1
                  THEN 'Complete'
                  ELSE 'Partial'
         END AS status
FROM     VTRCheckListDetails
GROUP BY userid,
         vtrRespDate
```

Comment: Ah, Foiled by the captcha and a dodgy internet connection!

Comment: Martin your query is also working great...nice :) thank you martin for the valuable query. wish i can make my SQL better eh :)